# How to use Kerberos in a NodeJS server?

Tags: node.js, security, authentication, windows-authentication, kerberos

I need to migrate a .net kerberos application to a nodejs environment.  The application currently takes an incoming request from a .net client and based on the domain and user within domain they are provided with a spgeno token if authenticated to use service.  The client then uses this token for all requests to a webservice.  I would like to replicate in nodejs however the modules are either poorly documented https://github.com/christkv/kerberos & https://github.com/auth0/kerberos-server or are focused on client side kerberos and not the server side usage.  I don't know c++ otherwise I would write bindings to the c/c++ interface so I can call from javascript code.  Does anyone have any suggestions on how to undertake migration?  Are there any good resources or modules that can be used that will help me?

Comment: I am still interested in an answer